# Why does this recursive method not work the same as while-true loop?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, while-loop

I'm working on my first endeavor into genetic algorithms and came across a weird bug when trying to implment pool selection. My original method used a recursive call to loop until a perameter was met, but this broke my evolution. When I switched it to a while loop everything worked suddenly. Then, I tried taking my old recursive method (acceptRejectBad1) and flipped the if statement to match the while loop, suddenly it worked but still took significantly more generations to reach the goal than the while loop method. Using a while loop might make more sense here anyway but I would like to understand why the recursive methods break down. Can anyone explain to me why these three methods behave so differently?

```
//recursive call method one
Guess acceptRejectBad1(double maxFit) {
  Guess parent = this.guesses[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(this.guesses.length)];
  if (parent.fitness <= ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(maxFit)) {
    return this.acceptRejectBad(maxFit);
  } else {
    return parent;
  }
}

//recursive call method two
Guess acceptRejectBad2(double maxFit) {
  Guess parent = this.guesses[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(this.guesses.length)];
  if (parent.fitness > ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(maxFit)) {
    return parent;
  } else {
    return this.acceptRejectBad(maxFit);
  }
}

//while-true loop method
Guess acceptReject(double maxFit) {
  while (true) {
    Guess parent = this.guesses[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(this.guesses.length)];
    if (parent.fitness > ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(maxFit)) {
      return parent;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you step through both methods in your IDE debugger to see what is actually happening?  That's the place to start.

Comment: It is said that usually while loops are faster than using recursion. What is it that "breaks" in the first approach?
Also, it seems this is heavily RNG-dependent. Have you ran enough iterations to see if they really differ that much? The debugger also affects execution speed.

Comment: What do you mean by _"this broke my evolution"_?  What actually happened with the first method?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem when i run it with the first method my new population doesn't improve and never reaches the goal, in this case finding the secret word. The second method does eventually evolve to reach the goal but takes many more generations.

Comment: @Tom The Guess objects have an array of characters and a fitness value which is how close they are to a secret word. the recursive loops should break when the random double from 0 to the max fitness of the previous population is <= the randomly selected Guess object. When I run the program it goes through several thousand generations and this method runs for each place in the population array so i do believe that they behave differently.